# Individual differences in response time (RT) - searching for the right test

Tags: categorical-data, differences

Given a distribution of response times to different categorical variables, what's the best way to test for individual differences?

or more specifically:

There are 100 people pressing buttons in 10 colors, with more than 200k presses collected altogether.
I want to test for individual differences in response-time (RT) to the buttons, what's the best way to do this?

(remember there are differences in response time in-between the different colors).

So far I thought of:

1. ANOVA - calculate a general (weighted) mean RT and compare to individual people.
2. The distribution level: compare the mean distribution of RT to individual distributions using:

   - chi-squared for goodness of fit
   - Kullback–Leibler divergence test
   - Kolmogorov–Smirnov test
3. Find a cool bayesian way to do it (which?)
4. Use a mixed-effect regression model, and calculate the marginal contribution of the people (R square test).

please help me decide - what's the best practice here?
I'd love to learn about another way I didn't think of that would do the trick.